# Use different name of the kustomization.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kustomize

For CI/CD purposes, the project is maintaining 2 kustomization.yaml files

1. Regular deployments - kustomization_deploy.yaml
2. Rollback deployment - kustomization_rollback.yaml

To run kustomize build, a file with the name "kustomization.yaml" is required in the current directory.
If the project wants to use kustomization_rollback.yaml and NOT kustomization.yaml, how is this possible? Does kustomize accept file name as an argument? Docs do not specify anything on this.

Comment: I'm afraid that changing the name of `kustomization.yaml` is not possible. Have you considered splitting the `Deployment` into 2 directories `kustomization_deploy`/`kustomization_rollback` with `kustomization.yaml` in each of them respectively?

Comment: Agree, there are different approaches to handle this, if the name change of kustomization.yaml is not possible

Answer (score 8):

Currently there is no possibility to change the behavior of `kustomize` to support other file names (by using precompiled binaries) than:

- `kustomization.yaml`
- `kustomization.yml`
- `Kustomization`

All of the below cases will produce the same error output:

- `kubectl kustomize dir/`
- `kubectl apply -k dir/`
- `kustomize build dir/`

```sh
Error: unable to find one of 'kustomization.yaml', 'kustomization.yml' or 'Kustomization' in directory 'FULL_PATH/dir'
```

Depending on the CI/CD platform/solution/tool you should try other way around like for example:

- split the `Deployment` into 2 directories `kustomization_deploy`/`kustomization_rollback` with `kustomization.yaml`

---

> As a side note!
>
> File names that kustomize uses are placed in the:
>
> - `/kubernetes/vendor/sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/pkg/constants/constants.go`
>
> ```golang
> // Package constants holds global constants for the kustomize tool.
> package constants
>
> // KustomizationFileNames is a list of filenames that can be recognized and consumbed
> // by Kustomize.
> // In each directory, Kustomize searches for file with the name in this list.
> // Only one match is allowed.
> var KustomizationFileNames = []string{
>   "kustomization.yaml",
>   "kustomization.yml",
>   "Kustomization",
> }
> ```
>
> The logic behind choosing the `Kustomization` file is placed in:
>
> - `/kubernetes/vendor/sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/pkg/target/kusttarget.go`

---

Additional reference:

- *[Github.com: Kubernetes-sigs: Kustomize](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Tasks: Manage kubernetes objects: Kustomization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/)*

Comment: @Girish your question was answered. Mark this as the correct answer.